# How does the alchemist's Stink Bomb work?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

The new FAQ clarifies that a [Stink Bomb](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/stink-bomb) will deal bomb damage to the target it hits.  My questions are:

- Does a Stink Bomb also deal splash damage to the surrounding targets?
- Can I use Precise Bombs to limit where the Stink Cloud appears?
- What is the Fortitude save for the created Stink Cloud?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Stink Bombs inflict "normal bomb damage", which means they still do their splash damage as well.  Precise Bombs will limit who takes the splash damage, but the fog cloud / stinking cloud spell still cover their [normal area](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/discoveries/paizo---alchemist-discoveries/smoke-bomb).  The Fort save DC is [determined as normal](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist#TOC-Discovery-Su-),

> 10 + 1/2 the alchemist's level + the alchemist's Intelligence modifier

per the PFSRD.

Comment: OK, so throwing a Stink Bomb produces three effects: direct damage to target, splash damage (controlled by precise bombs), and finally the stink cloud that I can't control.  Does that sound right?  Thank you!